# Help solving a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following:

$
y_{tt} = 25y_{xx},~0<x<\pi ,~t>0,;~y(0,t)=y(\pi,t)=0,~y(x,0)=y_{t}(x,0)=sin^2(x)
\\25X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0~~~~(1)
\\T(t)''+\lambda T(t)=0~~~~(2)
\\ X= sin(nx)~~~~(3)
\\T=C_{1}cos(5nt)+C_{2}sin(5nt)~~~~(4)
$
So: I obtained (3) and (4) by solving (1) and (2), respectively. I am not sure how to process (4) according to the initial conditions. Note: $ C_{1} and C_{2}$ are arbitrary constants. What I have been doing is, after plugging in $t=0$ getting $T=C_{2}sin(5nt)$ by assuming that since $u(x,t)=XT(0)$ that $T(0)$ must be equal to zero, and then solving the resulting homogenous equation. The next thing I think to do is $T'=C_{2}5nt*cos(5nt)$ but as far as figuring out how to make this equal $sin^2(x)$ as the conditions require I am lost. I am familiar with the use of Fourier sine series to determine what $C_{2}$ would be but I don't get the correct answer.

I do:
 $sin^2(x)=sin(nx) \\\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0,\pi}sin^2(x)sin(nx)dx= C_{2}
\\\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0,\pi}sin(nx)-cos(2x)sin(nx)dx
\\\frac{1}{\pi}[[\frac{1}{n}-cos(n\pi)+1]-\int_{0,\pi}[sin(2x+nx)+sin(2x-nx)dx]$

After this I don't know.

Comment: I would recommend using the align environment and separating your question into sections to make it easier to read, your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the homogeneous wave equation with fixed ends is

$$  \begin{align}\begin{cases} u_{tt} - c^{2} u_{xx} =0   & t > 0 , 0 < x  < L \\  u(0,t) =  u(L, t) = 0 &  t> 0   \\ u(x,0) = f(x) ,  u_{t}(x,0) = g(x) & 0 < x < L  \end{cases} \end{align} $$

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{ n c\pi t}{L} )+ B_{n} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) \sin(\frac{n c \pi t}{L})\bigg) $$

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \cos(\frac{ n c\pi t}{L} )+ B_{n}  \sin(\frac{n c \pi t}{L})\bigg) \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) $$

noting that $c^{2} = 25 $ and $L = \pi$ we have

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \cos(\frac{ 5 n \pi t}{\pi} )+ B_{n}  \sin(\frac{5n  \pi t}{\pi})\bigg) \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{\pi}) $$

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg( A_{n} \cos(5 n t )+ B_{n}  \sin(5nt)\bigg) \sin(n x) $$

The coefficients can be determined when

$$ A_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{2}(x) \sin(nx) dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{2 \cos( \pi n) -2}{n^{3} -4n} = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{\cos(n \pi) -1}{n(n^{2}-4)}$$

So for odd $n$ , $A_{n} = 0$ and $n =0, 2, -2$ don't exist.

Similarly

$$ 5 n B_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{2}(x) \sin(nx) dx  = \frac{2}{5 \pi n}  \frac{2 \cos( \pi n) -2}{n^{3} -4n} = \frac{4}{ 5 \pi n} \frac{\cos(n \pi) -1}{n(n^{2}-4)} $$